# Inserting records in one table getting records from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, db2

Hey Geeks I am new in DB2 I want to generate surrogates by getting maximum from one table and for that I am doing that

```
SELECT    *
FROM      ( SELECT    EMP_NAME ,
                    EMP_ID ,
                    ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ) ) g
          FROM      STG.EMPLOYEE AS A
                    LEFT JOIN PRD.INDIVIDUAL AS B ON A.EMP_ID = B.SRC_KEY
          WHERE     B.SRC_KEY IS NULL
        ) V
        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT ( COALESCE(MAX(INDVL_ID), 0) + 1 ) mm
                     FROM   PRD.INDIVIDUAL
                   ) B;
```

the above statement is used in **insert** statement.
In the above code I want to maximum which I get from last line.

```
(select EMP_NAME,EMP_ID,max(INDVL_ID)+(ROW_NUMBER() over())g) from 
 STG.EMPLOYEE)
```

May You guys got it and thanks in advance

Sample Data is here
 First table data

```
STG.EMPLOYEE
EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|  
     3|     def|
     4|     ghi|
```

Second table data from where i have to get  maximum

**PRD.INDIVIDUAL**

```
INDVL_ID|INDVL_NAME|SRC_KEY|
       1|       abc|      1|
```

**Output Table**

```
INDVL_ID|INDVL_NAME|SRC_KEY|
       2|       def|      3|
       3|       ghi|      4|
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: sample data uploded question is edited

Comment: Could that be solved by using a generated INDVL_ID column? Db2 would automatically increase the value and make sure it is unique.

Comment: Yes But that's the limitations. I have to generate self incremental surrogates I don't have to declare it as primary key or unique key

Comment: I'm not aware of any RDBMS that requires autogen columns be keys, although that's the standard practice (because of other constraints, they're not practical for much else).  DB2 also provides `SEQUENCE` objects.  Note that your current query is most likely **NOT** concurrency safe: if there are two inserts running at the same time, you're likely to get duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of allocating surrogate key values based on the current MAX value

```
INSERT INTO PRD.INDIVIDUAL 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER()   
        + (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(INDVL_ID),0) FROM PRD.INDIVIDUAL)  AS INDVL_ID
,       INDVL_NAME
,       SRC_KEY
FROM
    STG.EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! code-only answers might be considered as low quality and hence removed. Could you please edit your answer and elaborate on how this answers the question ?